# 4G LTE USB not working on ubuntu

Tags: usb-modem, 4g

I have bought a [4G LTE USB](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07PF8WBQ6/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?_encoding=UTF8&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title&th=1) from Amazon. It works on windows and i was able to connect to 4G using the software that comes with the USB.

I was trying to connect to use the USB on Ubuntu and raspberry pi, i followed the instructions from these [page](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-cellular-connections), but when I execute the command `$ sudo modem-manager.mmcli -i 0 --pin=<PIN>`, it gives me `successfully sent PIN code to the SIM`, but then the USB reboot automatically.

I tried to remove the pin from the SIM card, but the USB started to reboot directly before executing any command.

Can anyone help me to find a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you verify that this device works with Ubuntu?

Comment: The above notwithstanding, most of this devices do not require any special software in any OS. Most can be setup from their own "web server", i.e., they present themselves to the OS as a standard Ethernert-over-USB and the setup is done accessing its internal IP address from any browser.

Comment: When you connect the device, does it have any files in it? There might be some setup file for GNU/Linux

Comment: @ChanganAuto i have tried to access the router ip written in it, it didn't connect on the web browser even though the ping worked properly

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it does have a file for windows, but nothing for ubuntu

Comment: @David in the description on Amazon, it is written that it supports Linux. I have Ubutnu 18.04, and on raspberry pi 4, it is raspberry pi os (32 Bit)

Comment: There are many probably more then 30 different kinds of Linux. So I guess you have one it does not support. Good chance it is not for 32 bit as that is long gone.